# How can I enable USB in Virtual Box inside Freya?

Tags: release-freya, virtualization, virtualbox

I installed an Windows 7 Virtual Machine and everything is working fine, but to be able to identify USB devices inside my guest system it needs a function called "Groups" described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) that can be activated in Ubuntu. I tried to install in Freya but it didnt work at all (the menu option didnt apear and I'm not able to set all needed configuration). I wasnt able to find an specific solution that works in Elementary so here I am asking to you if you know any solution.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to enable USB support for vbox:

1. Install the appropriate vbox extension pack
2. Open terminal and execute this command

   `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER`
3. Go to settings > usb
4. Tick USB controller and USB 2.0 controller
5. Add an USB device filter.

Answer (score 2):

The simple GUI solution:

- Install `gnome-system-tools` from software center or with terminal command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
  ```
- Open `users and groups`

  [image: Imgur]
- Select the user ( your user name, if multiple users present)  and click on <kbd>Manage Groups</kbd>.

  A pop-up will appear, select `vboxusers` and click on <kbd>properties</kbd>

  [image: Imgur]
- Now check (enable) your user name.

  [image: Imgur]
- logout and login.

Now open vbox --> settings --> Usb

[image: img]

*Note*:

You can also enable via advanced options in `users and groups`.

Go to advanced options --> User privileges tab --> check Use Virtualbox virtualization solution (last in the list)